# Search all words that starts with $(' or with $(" but after that ther is no '# 'or '.'

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2013

Find with Regular expression, in Visal Studio search:
All words that starts with $(' or with $(" but after that ther is no '#' or '.'

So it should not find:

- $('#id1')
- $('.class')
- $(".class")

But it should find:

- $('div')
- $("span")

I try with this. But not working:

```
   $/(['"][^#/.].*
```

Comment: your escaping slashes are backwards. should be `\(` and `\.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\$\(((?!#|\.).)*\)
```

This should work for your cause.

in your regex you need

1)to escape `$` by `\$`
2)quanitfy your character class. ie. `[^#/.]*` and not `[^#/.].*` which just check for the first charcter after `("` and then allows `#` or `.`.

So your regex would be

`\$\(['"][^#.]*`

You also dont need to escape `.` in a charcter class.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sU3fA2/54

Answer (score 1):

Use lookarounds like below,

```
(?<=\s|^)\$\(['"](?![#.])\S+
```

OR

```
(?<=\s|^)\$\(['"](?![#.])[^()]*\)
```

OR

```
(?<=\s|^)\$\((['"])(?![#.])(?:(?!\1).)*\1\)
```

This won't match the wrong formats like `$("foo')`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xY3sK0/18)